# How to catch on a winform when the TAB key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed a Grid Control and I want that when Tab is pressed it jumps from on cell ot another. The issue is that no matters what event I suscribe or I override on the control when tab is pressed it never gets called. I also try to catch the Tab at the Form level but it's the same , any Key events respond to the TAB. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to override [IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Either PreviewKeyDown or KeyPress should work for you. Are you sure your GridControl got focus while you tested your code?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown is not just for WPF

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding ProcessCmdKey?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(GridControlFocused)
    {
        switch(keyData)
        {
           case Keys.Tab:
           // put code here to jump to next cell.
           return true;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `Form.KeyPreview = false`.

Comment: This has no effect on Tab key